# The tensorflow seems not to get installed

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Getting this same result:

pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow

P.S: I using Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the moment Tensorflow is only available as 64 bit version for Python 3.5 in Windows.

If you haven't the newest version of pip, update pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: It is giving this:
C:\Users\acer>pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Comment: Do you have the 64 bit version of Python? There aren't Tensorflow for the 32 bit version. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I have 64 bit version of Python installed but still when trying to install Tensorflow using the steps mentioned in the Tensorflow official site it is giving me the following result:
tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: The main problem was that I was trying to install tensorflow with Python 3.6 which is not supported. I created a conda environment for Python 3.5 and installed tensorflow with normal pip installation. It worked.

Comment: Why are you writing in your question that you use Python 3.5.2, when you are using Python 3.6?

Comment: I installed the conda with that version again (64 bit variant). But the time when I was posting this question it was 3.5.2. I am sorry I didn't update.